# Extract unspecified length of characters to the right of a pattern - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a function that returns a string value:

"D:\Put_Your_Temporary_Files_HERE\Auto_Receive\user_out-automation.ini:9:IpAccessListEx=1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|"

Everything after the equals sign can change depending on what's return in my function.  What I want to do is return all text after the equals (=) sign.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*`Select-String`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1) Cmdlet with `-Pattern` parameter to specify the text to find on [*input*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1#inputs)

```
$r = "IPAddressEx=|2.33.31.45|108.38.48.17|" | Select-String -Pattern "IPAddressEx=(.*)"
```

It [return *`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1#outputs) object on successful pattern match. So to get the sub group from match you have to the [access `Matches` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.matches?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#Microsoft_PowerShell_Commands_MatchInfo_Matches).

```
$r.Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple `-split` like

```
$str = "D:\Put_Your_Temporary_Files_HERE\Auto_Receive\user_out-automation.ini:9:IpAccessListEx=1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|"
($str -split '=', 2)[-1]
```

Result: `1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|`

**OR** use `-replace`:

```
$str = "D:\Put_Your_Temporary_Files_HERE\Auto_Receive\user_out-automation.ini:9:IpAccessListEx=1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|"
$str -replace '.*=(.+)$', '$1'
```

Result: `1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|`

**OR** use the regex `.Match()` method

```
$str = "D:\Put_Your_Temporary_Files_HERE\Auto_Receive\user_out-automation.ini:9:IpAccessListEx=1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|"
([regex]'.*=(.+)$').Match($str).Groups[1].Value
```

Result: `1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|`

**OR** even the String methods `IndexOf()` combined with `SubString()`:

```
$str = "D:\Put_Your_Temporary_Files_HERE\Auto_Receive\user_out-automation.ini:9:IpAccessListEx=1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|"
$str.Substring($str.IndexOf("=") + 1)
```

<sup>Although this last alternative is not advisable because `IndexOf()` may return `-1` if the search string is not found</sup>

Comment: Your regex pattern doesn't work. You need to include '.*=' in a positive lookbehind, i.e. `(?<=.*=)(.+)$`. At that point you can also omit the dollar sign and brackets, to get `(?<=.*=).+` as the shortest working pattern.

Comment: @martorad Nope. My regex works **because** of the anchor `$`. You obviously didn't try it.. For such a simple request, there is no need whatsoever to include a lookbehind.

Comment: Your regex **does not work**. I tested it both [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester), and in an actual powershell script. It returns the _entire_ string. Your first regex reference is `.*=`. This returns _all_ characters before an equals sign AND includes them in the output, which you can avoid by instead using a positive lookbehind `(?<=.*=)`.

Comment: While your capture group does indeed work, your regex is still not robust enough and will cause problems. Using a positive lookbehind does not use a vastly greater amount of resources :)

Comment: @martorad Please stop wining. The code works and is robust. No need for lookbehinds,

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Abdul's answer is to use regular expressions. For your case, this should work:

```
$ret = [regex]::match($string,'(?<=.*=).*')
if ($ret.Success) {
    $tag = $ret.Value
}
```

The regex uses a positive lookbehind, which finds all characters which precede an '='. It then finds all characters which follow it. It stores the object in $ret. You can get your value with $ret.Value.
This returns `1|131.203.181.66|1|10.21.5.34|1|109.146.13.135|1|10.21.3.3|`